# What's the default TLS version used by MSOLEDBSQL?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, oledb

I'm asking because Java 7 uses TLS 1.0 by default unless you explicitly stated otherwise in the connection string when using JDBC. I would like to know whether this is also the case with MSOLEDBSQL.

Comment: Presumably whatever is available in the operating system, Windows 10 should have TLS 1.2 and 1.3

Comment: @Charlieface The thing is, there can be multiple TLS versions enabled in the OS. Now which one of them is the default

Comment: The default is normally the highest available, except when you specify it

Answer (score 0):

This is not client library-specific.

> Note that the cipher suite for TLS/SSL and the authentication mechanism for SSPI and federated authentication are negotiated outside the influence of TDS in [RFC2246] and [RFC6101].

[TDS - 1.7 Versioning and Capability Negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/6809de85-1665-44ad-a459-6f6621e02257)

The important thing is that the cypher used is acceptable to both the client and the server.  So even if the client supports TLS 1.0, the server doesn't.

Comment: The thing is, both client and server has 1.0 and 1.2 enabled. I'm not sure which of them is used